# How to download SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) using anaconda?

Tags: machine-learning, anaconda, conda, shap, mamba

I am trying to install SHAP (SHapley Additive exPlanations) for machine learning using Anaconda.

I have 3.9 Python version.

Also, i have tried all of these commands but none of them worked:

```
conda install -c conda-forge shap
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 shap
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 shap
```

Comment: 1. Install 2. Reload your environment 3. Import 4. Share with us what you see

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Commands are not working :
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: this is an issue with conda

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov What can i do?

Comment: update your question with additional info

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fresh environment.

```bash
## create environment named foo
conda create --name foo -c conda-forge python=3.9 shap

## use the environment
conda activate foo
```